# How can I run a function after a get method completes fetching information in Angular?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, get

I have a get function that fetches data from my mongodb. The GET function takes a few seconds to run. Meanwhile, the function that is supposed to run next and work on the array of objects fetched does not wait for the array and runs giving an error. 
Is there any way I can run the function once my GET function finishes executing?

downloadVMclicked runs when ever i click the download button on my page.

```
downloadVMclicked(ctype){
     console.log("ctype ="+ctype)
     var vms= new Array<VM>();
     vms=[]
    this.clusters.forEach(element => {
      if(element.ctype==ctype)
      {
        this.inventoryService.getVMdownload(element.cname).subscribe(vmD =>{
          console.log("Concating this.vms "+vms+" vmDownload "+vmD)
          vms=vms.concat(vmD)
          console.log("vms length is"+vms.length)
          if(vms!=null)
          {
            console.log("VM downloaded for "+element.cname)
            console.log(vms)
          } 
          else
            console.log("VM not downloaded for "+element.cname)
        })
      }
    })
    this.download(vms);
   }

download(array){    
    console.log("Downloading "+ array.length+" items")
    var csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(array);
    var time = new Date();
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'vmAll '+time.toString()+'.csv';/* your file name*/
    a.click();
    return 'success';
   }
```

Comment: How do you fetch data? Share your code for us to understand

Comment: Sure: `service.get().subscribe(array => doSomethingWithTheArray(array))`

Comment: Edit your post to add the code ;)

Comment: The is no way **your data** will ever reach **this.dowload**. Cause you first use a **loop** and then use a **subscribe**. The **loop** will always be **faster** then the **subscribe** so the data of vms will never reach or it will partly. You just have to change your code and figure out a better way.
This can be an option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752086/how-to-wait-for-subscriptions-inside-a-for-loop-to-complete-before-proceeding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for subscriptions inside a for loop to complete before proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752086/how-to-wait-for-subscriptions-inside-a-for-loop-to-complete-before-proceeding)

Comment: @Swoox i can see in my console that the data has been fetched, but it also shows that the download function is being called before the data is fetched. The loop is working with subscribe to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the result already arrived, if yes, create a new promise and complete it with the result.

```
httpGet(url) {
    if(result === undefined) {
      return this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(
          result => this.result = result.json(),
          error => console.log(error);
      );
    } else {
      return new Promise().resolve(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to Angular and haven't used Promise before. I can't find anything about Promises on Angular.io. Is there some other website where I can find the information?

Comment: there are many blogs and post , you can check "medium" , also https://www.genuitec.com/angular-observables-and-promises/ you can find much details on observables/proimises

Comment: Hi, I have a question regarding the code that you posted. If the result is undefined then you are changing the result to JSON? Can you please explain your code. - @T.Shashwat