# Wait for SUBSCRIBE block to finish before completing loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a loop to repeatedly call API and print the corresponding response into a object but before my second subscribe is completed, loop moves on and execute the next line of code. How to appropriately wait for the subscribe to end before loop moves on ?

I want the array Phone to be populated completely before second loop kicks in.

```
getData() {
this.finaldata=[];
this.phone=[];
this.api.getSingleValue('/API/shift/app_name/' + this.application_name).subscribe((Response: any) => {  
  if (Array.isArray(Response) && Response.length > 0) {
     for(let i=0; i<Response.length; i++){
        this.api.getSingleValue('/API/person/' + Response[i].qlid).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.phone.push(res.contactNumber)   
      });  
    }
    console.log(this.phone)
    for(let i=0; i<Response.length; i++){
      this.object={
        "qlid": Response[i].qlid,
        "entry_Type": Response[i].entry_Type,
        "app_Name": Response[i].app_Name,
        "shift_Start_Time": Response[i].shift_Start_Time,
        "shift_End_Time":Response[i].shift_End_Time,
        "startDate": Response[i].startDate,
        "endDate": Response[i].endDate,
        "reason": Response[i].reason,
        "phone_no": this.phone[i]
      }
      this.finaldata.push(this.object);
    }
    console.log(this.finaldata)
    this.rowData = this.finaldata;
   
  }
  
  else{
    this.rowData=[];
    alert('No Data To Display')
    
  }
  
});

    
  }


}
```

Comment: Try solution of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752086/how-to-wait-for-subscriptions-inside-a-for-loop-to-complete-before-proceeding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid subscriptions in a loop and nested subscriptions. You could use RxJS operators to streamline your procedure.

Workflow on subscription:

1. Call `this.api.getSingleValue('/API/shift/app_name/' + this.application_name)` and switch it another observable using `switchMap`.
2. In the `switchMap`, use `iif` to check if the response is valid.
3. If yes, map the values in the array to `this.api.getSingleValue('/API/person/' + <response>.qlid))` array and use `forkJoin` to combine the observables. Use the `map` operator to further process the response, push values to `this.finaldata` variable and return it.
4. If not, throw the error using `throwError` operator.
5. In the subscription, handle the response (the `this.finaldata` variable) and the error using the `next` and `error` callbacks repspectively.

Try the following

```js
getData() {
  this.finaldata = [];
  this.phone = [];
  this.api.getSingleValue('/API/shift/app_name/' + this.application_name).pipe(
    switchMap((Response: any) =>
      iif(
        () => Array.isArray(Response) && Response.length > 0,
        forkJoin(Response.map(res => this.api.getSingleValue('/API/person/' + res.qlid))).pipe(
          map(phone => {
            this.phone = phone.map(number => number.contactNumber);
            console.log(this.phone);
            for(let i=0; i < Response.length; i++){
              this.object = {
                "qlid": Response[i].qlid,
                "entry_Type": Response[i].entry_Type,
                "app_Name": Response[i].app_Name,
                "shift_Start_Time": Response[i].shift_Start_Time,
                "shift_End_Time":Response[i].shift_End_Time,
                "startDate": Response[i].startDate,
                "endDate": Response[i].endDate,
                "reason": Response[i].reason,
                "phone_no": this.phone[i]
              }
              this.finaldata.push(this.object);
            }
            console.log(this.finaldata);
            return this.finaldata;
          })
        ),
        throwError('Response was empty');
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(
    (finaldata: any) => {
      this.rowData = finaldata;
    },
    error => {
      this.rowData = [];
      alert('No Data To Display')
    }
  );
}
```

#### Update: remove member variables except `rowData`

If you're using the `this.finaldata` and `this.phone` only to hold the information in this function, you could replace them all with local variables. Also you could use array `forEach` function instead of manually looping the array.

```js
getData() {
  this.api.getSingleValue('/API/shift/app_name/' + this.application_name).pipe(
    switchMap((Response: any) =>
      iif(
        () => Array.isArray(Response) && Response.length > 0,
        forkJoin(Response.map(res => this.api.getSingleValue('/API/person/' + res.qlid))).pipe(
          map(phones => {
            const contactNumbers = phones.map(phone => phone.contactNumber);
            let output = [];

            Response.forEach((res, index) => {
              output.push({
                "qlid": res.qlid,
                "entry_Type": res.entry_Type,
                "app_Name": res.app_Name,
                "shift_Start_Time": res.shift_Start_Time,
                "shift_End_Time":res.shift_End_Time,
                "startDate": res.startDate,
                "endDate": res.endDate,
                "reason": res.reason,
                "phone_no": contactNumbers[index]
              })
            });

            return output;
          })
        ),
        throwError('No Data To Display');
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(
    (finaldata: any) => {
      this.rowData = finaldata;
    },
    error => {
      this.rowData = [];
      alert(error)
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: This snippet works but not perfectly, like details from first API call like entry type etc( except QLID) is not populating, also inside phone no. whole response is biend sent instead of just contact no. from the second API call.

Comment: @IshankJain: Yes, I overlooked a key part. In the previous code the notification from the `forkJoin` would be wrongfully emitted to the subscription. I've edited the code to do all the processing using the `map` operator. It could then be assigned to `rowData` in the subscription callbacks. I've also used array `map` function to assign only the `contactNumber` from the `phone` array instead of the entire array. Please see if the updated answer works for you.